# PostgreSQL RULE tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation

While doing some research for a question, I realized that [`RULE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createrule.html) is a PostgreSQL extension and not part of the SQL standard.

However there doesn't appear to be a tag for RULES on this site, there are a number on Stack Overflow but [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rules) for example, has the following description:

> This tag is very broad, try being more specific by using tags relevant to your problem. Examples are "rule-engine" for rules engines, "url-rewriting"/"mod-rewrite" for rewrite rules or "form-validation" for validation rules. See the full wiki article for a more complete list.

Can we have a `postgresql-rule` tag for questions about `RULES`, or this overly specific?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt we have that many questions on it, but I don't see what damage that tag does. Normally you should be using triggers instead. If you want to add that tag, I say go for it. **I don't think it applies to the question of yours that I just answered though.**

Comment: Thanks. I posted this question because I don't have enough rep on this site to create a new tag